# Vue draggable to follow v-chip-group selection

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, draggable

I am using Vue draggable to change the position of my v-chips. When you click on a chip, the chip shows *Active* and is binded to `selection` with its index. The problem is that when you drag a chip and change its position it does not update the `selection` index.

How can I make sure one follows the other?

```
<v-chip-group
        v-model="selection"
        active-class="primary--text"
        column
>
    <draggable v-model="items" @start="drag=true" @end="drag=false">
        <v-chip v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i"
                close
                draggable>
            {{item.name}}
        </v-chip>
    </draggable>
</v-chip-group>
```

Comment: Can you please share the full component code includes javascript, also if you can able to create codepen. That will help us to solve your issue faster

Comment: Im on the codepen

Comment: Okie, please share the codepen link, we can solve your issue

Comment: Still working on it. Trying to add the ressource draggable to codepen.
https://codepen.io/phil94/pen/eYNqqVr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can able to set the selection index using @start and @end event in draggable component

Here is the working codepen: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/zYvOYyd?editors=1010

Find the working code here:

```
    <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card 
      max-width="400"
      class="mx-auto"
    >
      <v-card-text>
        <v-chip-group
          v-model="selection"
          column
          active-class="primary--text"
        >
          <draggable v-model="tags" @start="dragStart" @end="dragEnd">
            <v-chip v-for="(tag, i) in tags" :key="i" draggable>
              {{ tag.name }}
            </v-chip>
          </draggable>
        </v-chip-group>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    selection: null,
    currentTag: null,
    tags: [{
      name: 'Shoping',
    },{
      name: 'Art',
    }, {
      name: 'Tech',
    }, {
      name: 'Creative Writing'
    }
    ],
  }),
  methods: {
    dragStart() {
      if (this.tags[this.selection]) this.currentTag = this.tags[this.selection].name;
      else this.currentTag = null;
    },
    dragEnd() {
      var self = this;
      if (this.currentTag) {
        this.tags.forEach((x, i) => {
          if (x.name === self.currentTag) self.selection = i;
        });  
      }

    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in the console? This happens when you click and drag with no selection.

Comment: Also, if you select a chip and then unselect, when you click and drag a chip the selection reappears.

Comment: @Philx94, Added fix to  the above code and codepen, now it is working as expected. Let me know, this resolves your issue

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help. Unfortunately the two problems above are still encountered in the codepen.

Comment: There is no problem in the codepen https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/zYvOYyd?editors=1010, please let us know the exact error or expectation from you side

Comment: First problem: If you click on a chip, then drag that chip to a different position, then unselect, then drag an unselected chip to a new position, you'll have a chip selected. 
Second: If you drag a chip with no chip selected, you'll get an error in your console.

Comment: Added a fix to the above answer and codepen , now it is working as expected. Let me know your issue is resolved